# Flutter how to place a widget relative to another widget on screen?

Tags: flutter, layout, alignment

I want to place a paint board widget at the center of the screen and a clear button that sits top right above the paint board. I have tried column with MainAxisAlignment.center but it centers base on the board and clear button so the board is not absolutely at the center. How can I achieve this effect?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use positioned with stack and place where ever you want. copy and try this code in dartpad.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
    children: [
       Positioned(
         top: 100,
         child: Container(
           width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
           height: 250, color: Colors.yellow)),
       Positioned(
         top: 60,
         right: 20, 
         child: Icon(Icons.close, size: 32)),
    ]
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not clear enough, I want the yellow box to extend to screen width and red box should be placed above yellow box.

Comment: You can change the width of container by using mediaQuery. Isn't the current code show red box above the yellow ?

Comment: If its not can you add a image on how widget should look like ?

Comment: No, the read box is within the yellow box. image is added

Comment: I made a update in code, try it now. Value for positioned can be different, just play around with it

Comment: Have you really tested it on your phone? Please get it working first

Comment: WDYM ? I don't post code without testing it in DartPad

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar UI with a `Column` widget, you can add a `SizedBox` below the yellow box inside the `Column` with the same height as the `Icon`, so that the yellow box appears to be centred.

So, we can avoid hardcoded values inside thr `Positioned` widget (that impacts responsive UI)

Here is the code snippet.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double iconSize = 32;
    return Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        height: iconSize,
        child: Icon(Icons.close, size: iconSize),
      ),
      Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 250,
        color: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      SizedBox(height: iconSize)
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought about this too, but I prefer not to give it a fixed width. But probably I have no other options.

Comment: Do you mean the iconSize?